# How do I set up multiple networks to 1 computer with 4 ethernet cables with quad-nic (IS SOMETHING POSSIBLE?)

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet, nic

I'm not going to act like I know what I’m doing because obviously, I don’t. Complete n00b here.

So let's start with this. I have 4 networks. All 4 have their own router and switch.

- Mega Computer has 6 working Ethernet ports.
- We are on a VPN.
- Subnet is set to 255.255.255.240 for each network.
- The preferred DNS and alternate variables are the same on all networks
- The computers in each network run smoothly. Each computer can access the other's folder no
  matter the origin.  (as long as it is in the network)
- (these numbers are not the exact numbers) | 10.10.**148**.x | 10.10.**5**.x | 10.10.**148**.x | 10.10.**171**.x
- Only a range of 15 IPs are available to each network.
- Cables are 1 cat5e, 1 cat6, and 2 cat8
- All 4 have their own gateway

**My set up**: Now I added my Mega computer to 10.10.5.x  router. Works splendidly. I have an IP with 10.10.5.67.
When I want to send a 50gb file from my Mega computer to a computer in 10.10.5.x net-range, speeds are through the roof. 50gb in 10 mins max.

**The Problem:**  But when I try to send to the other computer on the other network's range, a simple 25gb takes about 30 mins - 1.5 hrs max. That is too slow...

I thought I knew what I was doing so I bought this: [Intel i350 T4](https://www.cdw.com/product/intel-ethernet-server-adapter-i350-t4-network-adapter-pcie-2.1-x4-gig/3522854?gclid=CjwKCAiAvdCrBhBREiwAX6-6UouiovqWiGaPTMEVwGPDBkv6B0ejcuMrnLrG1cJkzUHjEeEEs8dcVhoCyx8QAvD_BwE&cm_ven=acquirgy&cm_cat=google&cm_pla=NA-NA-Intel_NI&cm_ite=3522854&ef_id=CjwKCAiAvdCrBhBREiwAX6-6UouiovqWiGaPTMEVwGPDBkv6B0ejcuMrnLrG1cJkzUHjEeEEs8dcVhoCyx8QAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4223!3!198551352378!!!g!322637030099!!209536819!17663886379&gad_source=1)
Ran 1 ethernet from each one of the routers; Then ran all 4 to the back of that card.
In the control panel of the Mega computer, I set up the static IPs. So now each LAN connection on my

- Mega computer says something like this | 10.10.**148**.x | 10.10.**5**.x | 10.10.**148**.x | 10.10.**171**.x
  The problem is, that didn’t fix anything.  Speed to .5.x jumps to 120mb/s and levels around 70 ish. But to the other networks, it is 16mb/s down to 3mb/s

Then I tried setting up the [Intel ProSet Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkyUA.png), which made my life worse. So I tried creating a TEAM with the Intel Application with just the 4 adapters thinking this would work, and nothing.

Now I've been reading and reading, I asked around and received different vague answers. I've been told to try the VLAN thing, something I thought the Intel thing could do, unless idk what I'm doing there. I read somewhere where someone said, I need another router; I’m like how? And how would I connect it? I have a Netgear switch but it's unmanaged so maybe that will not help here.
My thing is, when sending to the connected network I’m in, yeah, I see speeds like 120mb/s but to those other ones, I’m stuck between 2mb/s - maybe 15mb/s.
But someone who knows what I am trying to achieve here, please help. Yes all computers touch the internet as well. But I do not need the internet. Heck, if I needed to, I can have 2 built in ethernet ports and can use it as the internet line. But I don’t think I have to do all that, nor will it solve the problem at hand. Oh and Windows 10 --if that matters.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I removed the TEAM and created a new team leaving out one of the x.148.x thinking maybe that was the problem. Still slow, I am deleting this.
So at the end of the day, I am trying to be able to send files over the networks at fast speeds.
Thank You

Comment: What kind of router do you have? When you are sending traffic between ranges the speed of the router decides the transfer speed

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I missed it, but I am not sure what OS you are using on these multihomed machines. Also, not clear why you separate the machines to different physical networks, are there security or business reason for that?

Most operating systems have built-in kernel modules for network aggregation, so you can construct a multi-wired multi-NIC aggregated backbone, appearing to application layer as a single network device. Although normally constrained to a single sub-net.

If that doesn't work for you, I suggest to check packet statistics for NICs that you consider slow. Chances are you may discover unusually high ratio of broken packets, and CRC errors, which may indicate a bad cable or NIC that needs replacement or a fault elsewhere on the network segment.

Some of these errors, however, may indicate NIC-to-NIC negotiation conflicts, like one asking for full-duplex, other restricting to half-dup. But such errors are quite rare these days.

Comment: Sorry, it was in  there with all the mumbo jumbo.